# Imagemagick: how to add border with text just below the image?

Tags: imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I need to add borders around photos and below the photo I want to append text. However, so far I can either add borders or add text, but they don't work togeter.

[image: original photo]

What I mean is, for appending text:

`convert photo.jpg -background White label:"A nice memory" -background White -gravity east -append result.jpg`

This adds a white strip with text at the bottom right of the image:

[image: Photo with text]

and for adding border:

`convert photo.jpg -bordercolor Green -border 5%x10% result.jpg`

[image]

It adds a nice green border around the photo. However, if I want them together:

`convert photo.jpg -bordercolor Green -border 5%x10% -background White label:"A nice memory" -background White -gravity east -append result.jpg`

[image]

it first adds a border, then an extra strip of space below the lower border with text. I guess I have to explicitly tell it to have border and text together. Is this possible?

Expected:

[image: Expected result]

(**Important**: I want the text to be right aligned with the photo as if there's no border)

Thanks!

Comment: A picture of what you have and another picture of what you want would be far better than several paragraphs describing what doesn't work...

Comment: exactly! let me do it.

Comment: @MarkSetchell added.

Answer (score 3):

```
convert input.jpg -bordercolor Green -border 5%x10% -gravity southeast -annotate +0+0 "Some text" result.jpg
```

Comment: Thanks! This works mostly, I'll need to figure out how to right-align the text with the photo itself, not with the border.

Comment: If you had a fixed border rather than a % you could adjust the +0+0 to something like -20+0 in the -annotate

Answer (score 0):

In Imagemagick 6, you can do it as follows (unix syntax):

```
infile="logo:"
offx=`convert $infile -format "%[fx:5*w/100]" info:`
offy=`convert $infile -format "%[fx:2.5*w/100]" info:`
convert $infile -bordercolor Green -border 5%x10% -font Arial -pointsize 18 -gravity southeast -annotate +${offx}+${offy} "Some text" result.jpg
```

In Imagemagick 7, you can do it as:

```
magick logo: -bordercolor Green -border 5%x10% -font Arial -pointsize 18 -gravity southeast -annotate +%[fx:5*w/100]+%[fx:(10/4)*h/100] "Some text" result.jpg
```

The offset (1/4 value) may need to be adjusted for the pint-size so that the text will be centered vertically in the space provided.

The image, logo:, is an internal Imagemagick image which requires the colon.